# How to convert character argument (decimal number) to numeric in R?

Tags: r, character, converters, numeric

I want to convert for example the number `167009345.8` to `167009345.8`.

I have used lots of ways but I have problems.

For example,

```
x <- "167009345.8"
class(x) <- "numeric"`
```

the output is `167009346`.

But I want the decimal number `167009345.8`.

I have used also `as.numeric`, but I have the same problem.

Could you please help me?

Comment: The internal representation of a number is not identical to what is printed to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
options(digits=10)
x<-"167009345.8"
as.numeric(x)
[1] 167009345.8
```

Comment: Well shorter would be ok, e.g. `as.numeric("123.01")` but I take your point about longer. Your solution is nice, but would return a character class. The user doesn't specify whether they want to any arithmetic on `x`.

Comment: True, I deleted my answer. However, there seems no option to define the number of digits printed after the decimal

Answer (score 0):

I had to split a long character string into separate decimal numbers. It was very frustrating. Maybe this can spare some others some time:

```
string = as.character("1.23456, -2.34567, -8.90, +0, +99999.9999, -0.0")
charlist = strsplit(string, "," )
numberlist = lapply(charlist, function(x) (as.numeric(x)))
vector = as.numeric(unlist(numberlist))
vector
[1]      1.23456     -2.34567     -8.90000      0.00000  99999.99990      0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution by @Meije the sheep. This was a great answer for me! I modified it a little for df processing.

My dataframe (`df`) has a character variable called `Score`.
Example values: "33.3333333333333" "51.8518518518518" "15.4471544715447"

To convert it to numeric (`Score_n`) I did the following, then dropped
`df$string`, `df$charlist`, and `df$numberlist`.

```
df$string = df$Score
df$charlist = strsplit(df$string, "," )
options(digits=10)
df$numberlist = lapply(df$charlist, function(x) (as.numeric(x)))
df$Score_n = as.numeric(unlist(df$numberlist))
```